# AutoDetect Tags from The Question Body

Tags: feature-request, tags

When I finish typing my question, I want the `Tags` section to autosuggest possible tags for me.

That would be a time saver.

Comment: I think they want to wait for LINQ-to-brain to come out of beta before implementing this.

Comment: Downvoted? You can disagree with me, but why need to downvote me?

Comment: On MSO, a downvote signifies disagreement with the feature request.

Comment: (and with discussions and bug reports too)

Comment: waiwai933 is correct; it's convention on Meta (in tradition with UserVoice) to use voting on feature requests as displaying agreement or disagreement. Besides that: nobody is downvoting *you* -- neither on Meta nor anywhere else. A downvote is on the *post*, not on the *user*.

Comment: This is actually now somewhat implemented. I've seen it working on certain sites

Answer (score 6):

I disagree strongly with this. The tags have a very defined and well-known purpose, and this purpose requires people to *think* about what tags to give to their questions.

If you auto-populated the tags field, people would just click "Post your question" without a second glance at the tags, essentially making tags a non-requirement. It's not like there's any software out there that is smart enough to figure out the correct tags from the question body, so the asker would still have to check through the suggestions -- but how would you enforce that?

Besides: **Asking questions isn't supposed to be fast**. When posting a question on SO, you are asked to take some time to thoroughly prepare the question, not to go from clicking "Ask a question" to clicking "Post your question" within the shortest possible time.

Answer (score 1):

Too difficult to implement in a way that avoids bad suggestions IMO. Too prone to produce tag clutter - it's very often that product or technology names get mentioned in posts that do not deserve a tag, because they are not essential to the issue in question.

The art of tagging a question is something everyone should master to some degree, and there is a strong "retagging movement" in the SO community to fix imperfectly tagged questions. I'd say leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea! I wish I had thought of this.

This would be difficult to implement - but for an example, look at how Yahoo! Answers handles categorization.

Comment: I'm not sure if invoking Yahoo! Answers is going to help sway the argument in the direction you're hoping. :)

Comment: @Ether: I'm not even sure what direction George is taking. My sarcasm detector somehow isn't working on this answer.